# How to configure network connections on Ubuntu server 18.x

Tags: system-installation

I am completely new to Ubuntu.
On page 4 of the installer, how do I configure network connections?
[The tutorial](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-server#6) says that it’s supposed to happen automatically, but it looks like it isn’t. It also says I can skip it and configure networking after installing, but it doesn’t seem like I can.
How do I configure network connections?

This is on page 4 of the installer. I’m not sure what I’m supposed to connect to. I want to set up a pinhole on this computer.

Comment: It's unclear if you wish help configuring a network connection during the install or if you want help configuring networking on an installed system. Please edit your question to clarify. It's also not clear what kinds of configuration help you are seeking. DHCP? IPv6? Bonding? Bridging? Help us to help you.

Comment: @user535733 During the install. I’m trying to set up a pi-hole

Comment: Set your router to communicate with the PI. Most folks do this by enabling DHCP on their router, We don't know anything about your network or your router settings, so we don't know if DHCP is appropriate for you or not. We only know that it's appropriate for most folks. Note that detailed settings for networking and routers are generally off-topic here, since they are not about Ubuntu.